# How to move string into ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am creating a new ViewModel that tally's up the results of a survey, performers some calculations on that data, and then returns the new calculation to a view.  I cannot figure out how to include regular "string" data in the collection.

```
 var data = from SurveyResponseModel in db.SurveyResponseModels
                       group SurveyResponseModel by SurveyResponseModel.MemberId into resultCount
                       select new ResultsViewModel()
                       {
                           MemberId = resultCount.Key,

                           UseNewTreatmentResult = db.SurveyResponseModels.Count(r => r.UseNewTreatment),
                           UseBetterTechniqueResult = db.SurveyResponseModels.Count(r => r.UseBetterTechnique),
                           ChangesOthersResult = db.SurveyResponseModels.First(r => r.ChangesOthers),

                       };
            return View(data);
```

The first part is counting boolean responses and passing them as an integer back to the ViewModel.  The section that includes `ChangesOthersResult = db.SurveyResponseModels.First(r => r.ChangesOthers),` Should just select the strings from the Model and pass to the ViewModel.  I am currently getting a syntax error about changing from type string to bool.  I'm not sure what the syntax for this is.

```
    public class SurveyResponseModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int ResponseId { get; set; }

        public int MemberId { get; set; }

        public int ProgramId { get; set; }


        [DisplayName("Use a new treatment")]
        public bool UseNewTreatment { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Use better/more updated technique")]
        public bool UseBetterTechnique { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Other (please specify):")]
        public string ChangesOthers { get; set; }



    }










 public class ResultsViewModel
    {

        public int MemberId { get; set; }

        public int ProgramId { get; set; }


        [DisplayName("Use a new treatment")]
        public int UseNewTreatmentResult { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Use better/more updated technique")]
        public int UseBetterTechniqueResult { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Other (please specify):")]
        public string ChangesOthersResult { get; set; }


    }
```

Comment: Can you post the exact error you get?

Comment: Btw, you have two dots here `SurveyResponseModels..First`... Is that a copy/paste error?

Comment: Whoops, should be fixed now.  The error I get says "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need:

```
ChangesOthersResult = db.SurveyResponseModels.Select(r => r.ChangesOthers)
```

Or `SelectMany`. Eventually add `FirstOrDefault()` at the end depending on what type `ChangesOthersResult` is and what you actually want to select.

`Select` gives you a "collection of collections" (I am assuming that `ChangesOthers` is a collection type). `SelectMany` a "flattened collection" of the generic type of your `ChangesOthers` collection. Adding `FirstOrDefault()` after `Select` gives you the single collection of the first `SurveyResponseModels` entity - or `null`.

**Edit**

After you supplied the classes I see that `ChangesOthers` and `ChangesOthersResult` aren't collections but just of type `string`. So the line should be:

```
ChangesOthersResult = db.SurveyResponseModels.Select(r => r.ChangesOthers)
    .FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: Think I'm getting close...  Now I'm getting an error saying "cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<String>' to 'string'.  Is this because of an incorrect data type in my ViewModel?

Comment: @user547794: Maybe. Can you show the `ResultsViewModel` and the `SurveyResponseModel` entity type as well in your question?

Comment: Ok, I have updated the question to include the Model and ViewModel

Comment: @user547794: BTW: Are you sure that you don't want to use the grouping variable `resultCount`? Your query counts the elements in the whole table, for every group the same, and not the elements in each group.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I did mean to use resultCount.  Still trying to get a grasp on LINQ to Entities.  I appreciate the help!